# How do I find which input field was focused when enter was pressed? (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have 3 input fields (textfield) in my form.

```
<input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" value="">
<input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value="">
<input id="input3" name="input3" type="text" value="">
```

I also have this piece of javascript:

```
$("#timetable").on("submit", function(event) {
    console.log("input " + $("input").attr("id") + "has focus");
});
```

I would like to know which input field has focus when the enter/return button was pressed. I've searched the net but came away empty.

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(event);` + `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: What is the html element whose id is *timetable* ?

Comment: @VitorLima Presumably a `<form>` element since the `submit` event listener is attached to it.

Comment: If the user clicks on the submit button, you will not want to know what was the input field that was selected? Do you want to know it just in the case the user press enter? Because, if this is the case, I think the Crozier's answer is right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**MDN - `Document.activeElement`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)
>
> `Document.activeElement` returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any. This attribute is read only.

Therefore within the submit event listener, you would access [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement), which is the focused element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mghxvjh6/)

```
$("#timetable").on("submit", function (event) {
    console.log(document.activeElement);    // element
    console.log(document.activeElement.id); // element id
    
    $(document.activeElement).css('border-color', 'red');
});
```